# IOS HMAC-SHA1 Different than Standard Java HMAC-SHA1

Tags: java, ios, objective-c, ios5, ios6

I need cHMAC with SHA512 encryption I got using encrypted value this method  and server side value is not matched server side they are using Java can plz help me to figure this issue.

serverside encrted value is

```
85d86c928825ef85d5329893f2cf2cba9ba6354582d54b5f1c7aaf69b6d72f71b742ae67f3e400d2e4b367f62a45b9948b512ae9a8efc0bcd667f1cdb0a66c6d
```

objective-c encrypted value is

```
  f242340a3664ea149717b943087cb8a5d92d6d25af5f5d8e0f51a6c4f0c1060830128e0798e6b300a81a1401612f0000d75d0000d3e27401e8d9ffbf221e1401
```

Objetive-C code:

```
-(NSString *)createSHA512:(NSString *)string withKey:(NSString *)key
 {
NSLog(@"key isss %@",key);
NSLog(@"string isss %@",string);

const char *cKey  = [key cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
const char *cData = [string cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

unsigned char cHMAC[CC_SHA512_DIGEST_LENGTH];

CCHmac(kCCHmacAlgSHA256, cKey, strlen(cKey), cData, strlen(cData), cHMAC);

NSData *HMACData = [[NSData alloc] initWithBytes:cHMAC length:sizeof(cHMAC)];

const unsigned char *buffer = (const unsigned char *)[HMACData bytes];
NSLog(@"bytes data is %@",HMACData);

NSString *HMAC = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:HMACData.length * 2];

for (int i = 0; i < HMACData.length; ++i)
    HMAC = [HMAC stringByAppendingFormat:@"%02lx", (unsigned long)buffer[i]];

return HMAC;
}
```

Java code:

```
public static String SHA512(String ta, String key, String xtra){
Digest digest = new SHA512Digest ();
HMac hmac = new HMac(digest);
String temp =ta.concat(key.concat(xtra));
hmac.init(new KeyParameter(key.getBytes()));
hmac.update(temp.getBytes(), 0, temp.length());
byte[] resBuf = new byte[digest.getDigestSize()];
 hmac.doFinal(resBuf, 0);
String resStr = convertToHex(resBuf);
return resStr;
}
```

Where have I made a mistake? if anyone know regarding this can u please share me to solve this issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't find documentation for the `HMac` class you're using, but I strongly suspect you're using the `doFinal` method incorrectly. I suspect you want:

```
byte[] results = hmac.doFinal(temp.getBytes(), 0, temp.length());
```

... although you *really, really* shouldn't use `getBytes()` like this, with the platform default encoding. It would be better to write:

```
byte[] binaryData = temp.getBytes("UTF-8");
byte[] results = hmac.doFinal(binaryData);
```

EDIT: As noted in comments, you're using ASCII in the Objective-C code. You should pick an encoding and use it in both places - I'd recommend UTF-8.

Comment: Of course if you use "UTF-8" on the Java side then you'll need to use NSUTF8StringEncoding to match.